# Wix checking Silverlight version

Tags: silverlight, wix

In my *Wix bootstrapper* I magage to get hold of the installed version of *Silverlight* with:

```
 <Variable Name="SilverLightSearch" Value="0" Type="version"  />
 <util:RegistrySearch Id="SilverLightSearchId" Format="compatible" 
 Root="HKCR" Key="AgControl.AgControl\CurVer"
 Variable="SilverLightSearch" />
```

In the install log I get this:
Setting string variable `SilverLightSearch` to value `AgControl.AgControl.5.1`

However in my `DetectCondition` I cant compare against it

```
    DetectCondition="SilverLightSearch = AgControl.AgControl.5.1"
```

*Always returns false*.

Ideally I would compare against this and later versions, as in greater than 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Format="raw" Result="value"  Root="HKCR" Key="AgControl.AgControl\CurVer" Variable="SilverLightSearch" />
```

and the condition:

```
DetectCondition="SilverLightSearch >= v5.1"
```